# Excluding nested form fields in controller action with Hash#exclude before mass_assignment error is generated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have a create action in my sales controller that looks like this:

```
def create
    @sale = Sale.new(params[:sale].except(:vehicles_attributes))
    if @sale.save
      redirect_to @sale, :notice => "Successfully created sale."
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
end
```

The intention is to exclude a couple of attributes that are used only to populate linked selects, and should not be submitted (there are no columns for them).

With the controller code above, I am finding that the parameters still includes `"sale"=>{"vehicles_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"make"=>"","model"=>""}}}` so it seems that I have missed something in the controller code.

EDIT: After some more digging around, I have found that the mass_assignment exception is firing before my except code gets a chance to remove the params that shouldn't be sent by the form, so I am back to square one.

How can I ensure that I remove the fields that shouldn't be sent by the form before I get the mass_assignment error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the mass_assignment error should occur during the `new` call, so your way should work. Although I never used the `except` method. Have you tried using the `reject!` method?

```
def create
  params[:sale].reject! { |k, v| k == :vehicles_attributes }
  @sale = Sale.new(params[:sale])
  if @sale.save
    redirect_to @sale, :notice => "Successfully created sale."
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

If you need to keep the `:vehicles_attributes` you can also use the `reject` method (without the bang) which gives you a copy instead of removing it from the original hash.

Comment: I think you might have hit on the answer - I have been putting my code in the create action, so if the mass assignment error is occurring in the new call, that will be why my code is not correcting the problem. Though putting the same code in the new action seems to be trying to apply it at the time of the page load, not when the form is submitted?

Comment: No, no... I was referencing to the `Sale.new` call, not the new method of your controller. The place you chose to interfere with the params hash should be correct.

Comment: BTW: How is your `Sale` model set up exactly? You also mentioned in your question, that some part of your form shouldn't be sent but it is anyway? What does your View look like?